# Sorting before Grouping, and vice-versa : which is faster?

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, performance, group-by

Just throwing this out here 'cause I became curious after hearing my colleague's predicament.

In a general production environ query, would it be faster to **sort first before grouping**, or to **group first before sorting**?

And yeah, a *general* production environ. I know that this is dependent on a lot of things:  how many rows you're querying from, how many rows the initial result set is, how many columns, what DB schema I'm using, whether or not it's bound to rain tomorrow, etc. I know, I know. I'm saying *general* because I don't really have any bounds to explicitly set this curiosity of mine on.

Let's just say, based on your experience, which tends to be faster?

Comment: I've never tried comparing them, but I'd be very surprised if you saw a difference. Isn't the SQL engine going to optimize this for you?

Comment: Gah, want to close as not a real question.  Answer:  It depends on the database, what is in it, its schema, indexes, etc.

Comment: **Performance questions are unanswerable without specifics!**  You may as well ask "which is faster, a 5 speed manual or a 6 speed automatic?" without specifying, you know, what car(s) you are talking about.

Comment: please define what 'sort first before grouping' really means... Grouping is sorting of sort anyway... It's almost obvious that if you want results of GROUP BY sorted then reducing data set first (by grouping) is faster. But just look up query plan in your db engine to see what your db thinks...

Comment: @Will ~ if it doesn't match your idea of a real question, then be my guest. No biggie.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan: Eh, people have already answered.  The community speaks, so to... speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group it is necessary to sort first (the engine will do it). And if you try to sort first then the result is not necessarily sorted:

```
select a, sum(b)
from (
    select a, b
    from c
    order by a 
    ) d
group by a
```

So don't try to sort first because you will need to sort after anyway and it will just make your code confusing.

Comment: Although the question didn't make much sense reading it (even to me!), I have to say that this is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks.